# How do I shrink a non-boot drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

How do I go about shrinking a non-boot drive? I've read through all of the questions on here and can't find a thread similar to mine. I have a 931.51GB NTFS partition (D:/), and I'm trying to Shrink it using the Windows Disk Management tool.

So, first off, it tells me that I can shrink up to 154.027GB. [image]

After I do this (I change the value to 100000 (100GB) instead, as that's what I want to shrink it by), I get an error after about 5 minutes: [image]

I guess I'm just not sure what to do at this point. I have a lot of data on there that I'd really like to not have to delete, but if I have to, then I have to. I'm trying to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu (or Mint) and the automated installer is failing to resize my partitions - I came on windows to try it here, and I have the same exact problem - there's definitely something going on here.

Here is a picture of my current Disk Manager display:
[image]

### **Things I've tried:**

-chkdsk C: /f (found/fixed errors, still no luck)
-chkdsk D: /f (found/fixed errors, still no luck)

 
-WinDirStat to see if there are any weird files, and I did not see any ( but I don't know the tool that well) 
I also noticed that Windows says that D is the "primary" drive, even though it's installed on my SSD (C:/).

I appreciate any and all feedback. If by some chance this question WAS posted elsewhere, I apologize in advance and I'll be happy to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say Windows is just having a bad day. When all else fails do it yourself. Try to manually fix your problem: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

This nifty program can shrink and move partitions when Mr. suborn Windows fails. gParted is linux only, but is included in Live Ubuntu CD's (Possibly Mint). (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Alternately you can download just gParted and boot from that. (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)

Here is a full tutorial: I recomend printing it before trying anything (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/)

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I ended up formatting the entire drive, as I think there was just something weirdly wrong with it. There was a hidden MBR somewhere on my alternate drive, and that's what was causing the issues. I managed to get rid of it and things were fine. Thanks again for all of your help though, I appreciate it. +1 and marking your answer as best.